# Rotativa ViewAsPDF Very slow on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

**What Have I done so far**

I am working on a program where I have sort of a receipt that can be showed to the user. When this occurs, I have a button where one can click to generate that receipt as a pdf. I have accomplished this on my local laptop using Rotativa ActionAsPdf and ViewsAsPDF. But this is where my success comes to a crashing halt.

**Problem**

I moved all this to a server and ActionAsPdf absolutely refuses to work, I must have read at least 23 post that talks about dll and runtimes and placing it in the Rotativa folder but none of that worked for me. I attempted to use ViewAsPdf where I again enjoyed some success but that once again was short lived when I moved the code to the server.
The rendering of the pdf, while it takes about 1/2 on my laptop is painfully slow on the server I saw forum post talking about external css and adding "--print-media-type" but none of that has solved my issue. I should also note that I can run wkhtmltopdf manually.

Please find code below

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult viewInvoice(Guid cartID)
{

    var invoice = from t in db.Transactions
                  join p in db.Payment_Types
                    on t.paymentTypeId_FK equals p.paymentTypeId
                  join c in db.Carts
                    on t.cartId_FK equals c.cartId
                  join u in db.Users
                    on c.accountId_FK equals u.Id
                  join d in db.Departments
                       on p.deparmentId_FK equals d.departmentId
                  join m in db.Ministries
                      on d.ministryId equals m.ministryId
                  where t.cartId_FK == cartID
                  select new
                  {
                      t.amount,
                      c.totalAmount,
                      p.name,
                      c.invoiceNum,
                      c.datePaid,
                      c.taxAmt,
                      c.finalAmt,
                      c.cartId,
                      u.FirstName,
                      u.LastName,
                      d.departmentName,
                      m.ministryName
                  };


    ViewBag.minName = invoice.Select(e => e.ministryName).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.departmentName = invoice.Select(e => e.departmentName).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.datePaid = invoice.Select(e => e.datePaid).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.invoiceNum = invoice.Select(e => e.invoiceNum).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.fullName = invoice.Select(e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.amount = invoice.Select(e => e.totalAmount).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.taxAmt = invoice.Select(e => e.taxAmt).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.finalAmt = invoice.Select(e => e.finalAmt).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.cartId = invoice.Select(e => e.cartId).FirstOrDefault();


    OrderHistory orderHistory = new OrderHistory();

    orderHistory.no = db.vw_OrderHistory.Where(d => d.cartId_FK == cartID).Select(d => new noVm
    {


        amount = d.amount,
        name = d.name,

    }).ToList();




    var z = new ViewAsPdf("InvoicePreview", orderHistory);

     z.Cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => Request.Cookies[k].Value);
    z.FormsAuthenticationCookieName = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    //z.CustomSwitches = "--load-error-handling ignore";
    //z.CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type";
    //z.FormsAuthenticationCookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    return z;

}
```

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<head>

 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 

    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Content/assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 
    <!-- prism css -->
    <!-- vendor css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/assets/css/style.css">
    <title> </title>
 

    @*<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code. jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="main-body ">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- [ Main Content ] start -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- [ Invoice ] start -->
            <div class="container" id="printTable">
                <div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="row invoice-contact">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="invoice-box row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <table class="table table-responsive invoice-table table-borderless">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    @*<td><img src="~/Content/assets/images/logo-dark.png" class="m-b-10" alt=""></td>*@
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a class="text-secondary" href="sdm" target="_top"> </a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table width="100%" style="margin:auto;vertical-align:top" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" width="30%">
                                        <h6>Client Information :</h6>
                                        <h6 class="m-0">@ViewBag.fullName</h6>
                                        @*<p class="m-0 m-t-10">1065 Mandan Road, Columbia MO, Missouri. (123)-65202</p>
                                            <p class="m-0">(1234) - 567891</p>
                                            <p><a class="text-secondary" href="mailto:demo@gmail.com" target="_top">demo@gmail.com</a></p>*@
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" width="30%">
                                        <h6>Order Information </h6>
                                        <table class="table table-responsive invoice-table invoice-order table-borderless">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><b> Date :</b> @ViewBag.datePaid</td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><b>Status :</b>   <span class="label label-success">Paid</span></td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    @*
                                                        <th>Id :</th>
                                                        <td>
                                                            #146859
                                                        </td>*@
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" width="30%">

                                        <h6 class="m-b-20">Invoice Number: <span>@ViewBag.invoiceNum</span></h6>
                                        <h6 class="text-uppercase text-primary">
                                            Total Paid :
                                            <span>$@ViewBag.finalAmt</span>
                                        </h6>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table  invoice-detail-table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="thead-default">
                                                    <th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th style="text-align:right;padding-right:100px">Total</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach (var item in Model.no)
                                                {
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <h6>@item.name</h6>
                                                            <p>@ViewBag.minName - @ViewBag.departmentName</p>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td style="text-align:right;padding-right:100px">@item.amount</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
                                                @*<tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <h6>Logo Design</h6>
                                                            <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </p>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>7</td>
                                                        <td>$100.00</td>
                                                        <td>$700.00</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <h6>Logo Design</h6>
                                                            <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </p>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>5</td>
                                                        <td>$150.00</td>
                                                        <td>$750.00</td>
                                                    </tr>*@
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <table class="table table-responsive invoice-table invoice-total">
                                        <tbody style="padding-right:90px">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Sub Total :</th>
                                                <td>$@ViewBag.amount</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Service Charge(3%) :</th>
                                                <td>$@ViewBag.taxAmt</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            @*<tr>
                                                    <th>Discount (5%) :</th>
                                                    <td>$45.00</td>
                                                </tr>*@
                                            <tr class="text-info">
                                                <td>
                                                    <hr />
                                                    <h5 class="text-primary m-r-10">Total :</h5>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <hr />
                                                    <h5 class="text-primary">$@ViewBag.finalAmt</h5>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h6>Terms And Condition :</h6>
                                    <p>

                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- [ Invoice ] end -->
        </div>
        <!-- [ Main Content ] end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have alot database wise going on but I don't think that's the speed issue. However, I first show the invoice, then I have a button which calls ViewAsPdf that does the same computations all over again, and I dont think this is the best. Also I am looking for alternatives to Rotativia , any help is appreciated.

Comment: " ActionAsPdf absolutely refuses to work" does not seem to be performance problem at all... Are you sure you meant to write that? Also you may want to remove request for libraries from the post (unless it is your actual question... which you know is off-topic)

Comment: I mean ActionAsPDF does not work when placed on the server, I have also tried all dll and nothing helped

Comment: Could you provide a list of the Rotativa related files that you are uploading to the server inside your application folder for IIS? Please check that you have at least these files (guessing "appfolder" as the name for the physical path to your application):
- \appfolder\bin\Rotativa.dll
- \appfolder\App_Browsers\qt.browser
- \appfolder\Rotativa\wkhtmltoimage.exe
- \appfolder\Rotativa\wkhtmltopdf.exe
Are you receiving any error on your app logs when you use Rotativa on server?